# Appium (Java): How to create a card reading process in the background and to simultaneously validate the android screens displayed

Tags: java, multithreading, appium

I am trying to automate the android app using Appium. This app runs on an android device that is connected to the payment card reader. When user swipes the credit card in the reader, then based on the card read (which happens in the background) the corresponding screen is displayed. For example before the card is verified, user is asked if the what a receipt. User is required to click on Yes or No button on the screen then the card is verified(in the background) and Thank you screen is displayed. I have simulated the card reader using Java.

What i need to do is run the credit card read simulation program in the background. But in the mean time  I need to validate the screens which is displayed on the different stages and awaits user inputs like `click()` on webElements etc.

I am struggling to come up with ideas on how to achieve this. Could you please help me?

For now what I did was

```
public class AppiumTestClass extends base {

    @Test
    public void classA() {
        driver = capabilities("android_app"); // the name is taken from the global properties file
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        CardReader cr = new CardReader();
        cr.cardReaderSimulate();

    }

    initiated driver
    in the base class

}
```

```
public class CardReader {

    public openSerialPort(){
        .. code to open serialPort
    }

    public readSerialPort(){
        .. code to read from serialPort
    }

    public writeSerialPort(){
        .. code to write to serialPort
        within this code I have implemented the user inputs like clicking on an element on the screen         
        (using Page objects)
    }

    public closeSerialPort(){
        .. code to open serialPort
    }

    public cardReaderSimulate(){
        openSerialPort();
        readSerialPort();
        writeSerialPort();
        closeSerialPort();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found out a way to do this.

TestNG Test cases instantiates the Android device terminal java program  which in turn calls the Card Reader program.

public class AppiumTestClass extends base{

```
public void parkerEnters(){

Terminal et = new Terminal();
```

}
}

public class Terminal{

```
public void terminalEnt(){

CardReader cd = new CardReader();

//other validations and process
}
```

}

public class CardReader{

```
//process to read the credit card
```

}